# form in rows with details for labels

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form which looks like this[image: form]

How will I get the 3 columns and the rows within ? I tried using class="col-md-4" 
then within it I created two divs with float left

```html
<label for="Halves">Halves</label> &nbsp;<label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label><input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" size="10"/>
```

but still not sure how to get the rates under Halves (as per image)

Comment: In order to have rows within columns, use `<row>` in each column.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/61/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6"> Halves</label> 
            <label class="control-label"> Quantity</label> 
            <input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" size="10"/>  
            <div class="input-group">
                <i>$14.5 per LB</i>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>    
</div
```

The above structure can be expanded to multiple columns/rows.